# Определить количество согласных и частоту повторения каждой из них

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки

Проблема в том, что у программа неправильно считает количество согласных вообще.
Может проблема в том, что компилятор не понимает русский язык?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int consonantsNumber(const string &str) {
    int result = 0;
    string consonants = "бвгджзйклмнпрстфхцчшщ";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < consonants.size(); j++)
            if ( tolower(str[i]) == consonants[j] ) {
                result++;
            }
    return result;
}

int main() {    
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    cout << consonantsNumber(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Конечно, компилятор не понимает. Вернее, не компилятор. А Ваша программа. 1) В какой кодировке Вы пишете буковки в программе? 2) в какой кодировке вводите строку в консоли? Вы думаете, они совпадают? А они однобайтные хотя бы? - Если однобайтные, то все лечится просто добавлением пары команд, а вот если там юникод... Нужно будет еще чего-то куда-то конвертировать перед тем, как сравнивать...

Comment: Хорошо, я понял, а можно как-то без свитча и без кучи if else найти количество повторений каждой буквы?

Comment: Ну, еще можно использовать функции из `string` типа `find_first_of()` и т.п. - они умеют искать символ из предоставленной строки (т.е. ей можно скормить Вашу `consonants`). И можно совместно с ней использовать ассоциативный массив (`map`) для ведения статистики по каждому символу (букве) - опять же, чтобы отвязаться от условий. Но я не уверен, что так будет нагляднее, чем с `if/switch`. И быстрее тоже вряд ли станет.

Comment: Либо можно воспользоваться функциями из Си, типа `strpbrk`. Даже похожий пример есть: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strpbrk/  (про гласные).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю для решения вашей проблемы следует воспользоваться std::map

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    std::string cs = "бвгджзйклмнпрстфхцчшщ";
    std::map<char, int> consonants;
    for (auto ch : cs)
        consonants.emplace(ch, 0);
    std::string entr;
    std::getline(std::cin, entr);
    for (auto ch : entr)
        if (consonants.find(ch) != consonants.end())
            consonants.find(ch)->second++;
    for (auto consonant : consonants)
        std::cout << "Кол-во буквы " << consonant.first << " в тексте: " << consonant.second << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```